# Can't sort my hash in my perl script

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

```
sub hashOfUsers
{
    %userAndPass = (); #hash to store the user and passwd, SORT hashes to view     the users of this program
    $userAndPass = {
        USER1 => 'David',
        PASS1 => 'P@ssw0rd',
        USER2 => 'Paul',
        PASS2 => 'P@ssw0rd',
        USER3 => 'Diana',
        PASS3 => 'P@ssw0rd'
      }; #users and pass hashes
}

sub option4
{
    &hashOfUsers();
    foreach $hi(sort {$userAndPass{$a} cmp $userAndPass{$b}} keys %userAndPass)
    {
        print "The users of this programs are: $userAndPass{$hi} $hi  \n";
    }
}
```

i can't seem to be able to sort my hash, im using this foreach in sub option4 loop in my subroutine trying to sort my hash. I am trying to sort it so that it prints out ONLY the users, from USER1 to USER3 and not the PASS1 to PASS3. Please help.

Comment: That doesn't produce the output you claim it does. Specifically, it produces no output. Start by adding `use strict; use warnings qw( all );` -- always use these!!! -- and fixing the problems they find.

Comment: Was the structure `$userAndPass` given to you or did you make it up yourself? I'd suggest a far better structure for storing usernames and passwords...

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to use numbered keys in a hash. If ordering is important - then it's a job for an array. If ordering isn't important, and you have named key-value pairs, then it's a job for a hash.

Oh, and in your case - `%userAndPass` is not related to `$userAndPass`. `use strict;` `use warnings;` would have told you this.

I would suggest your data structure would be much better as:

```
my @users = (
   {  USER => 'David',
      PASS => 'P@ssw0rd',
   },
   {  USER => 'Paul',
      PASS => 'P@ssw0rd',
   },
   {  USER => 'Diana',
      PASS => 'P@ssw0rd'
   }
);
```

Because then you can:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@users;
print $users[1]->{USER},"\n";

print $_->{USER},"\n" for @users;
```

Comment: Exactly this structure I had in my mind. The sorting can then be done like this: `foreach my $entry ( sort { $a->{USER} cmp $b->{USER} } @users ) { print "user: $entry->{USER}; pwd: $entry->{PASS}\n"; }`.

Answer (score 1):

## The Problems:

First, you initialize your structure as a scalar reference to a hash, but your `sort` statement wants to use a (currently uninitialized) hash.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Just do it!

If you were to:

```
%userAndPass = (
    USER1 => 'David',
    PASS1 => 'P@ssw0rd',
    USER2 => 'Paul',
    PASS2 => 'P@ssw0rd',
    USER3 => 'Diana',
    PASS3 => 'P@ssw0rd'
  );
```

The `sort` function in your `foreach` statement would produce some variant of the following list:

- `USER1`
- `USER3`
- the `PASS*` keys in random order (their associate values are all identical)
- `USER2`.

The heart of your problem with this structure is that your Usernames & passwords are only associated with each other by accident of your key choices.  (If you are numbering your variable names or keys, you should stop & reconsider.  It's a code-smell.)

## Redesign:

Structures that may be less insane include:

### An array of "records":

```
@UserAndPass = (
  {USER => 'David', PASS => 'P@ssw0rd'},
  {USER => 'Paul',  PASS => 'P@ssw0rd'},
  {USER => 'Diana', PASS => 'P@ssw0rd'},
);
```

This can be sorted directly. (As in Sobrique's simultaneous solution.)

or

### A hash of passwords keyed on username:

```
%UserAndPass = (
  'David' => 'P@ssw0rd',
  'Paul'  => 'P@ssw0rd',
  'Diana' => 'P@ssw0rd',
)
```

This can be used creating a sorted list of keys, more like your original code seems to want to do.  This structure has the advantage of being 1 level shallower, but the "disadvantage" that you can't have multiple passwords for the same user (if you're into that sort of thing =/  ).

---

If the current code-smell version of the structure is important to you, consider replacing `keys %UserAndPass` with `grep {/^USER/} keys %UserAndPass`